# What other beer brands began as fictional but eventually became real?

Tags: history

[Duff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff_Beer) is the only one of which I am aware. I know there are [Game of Thrones](http://www.ommegang.com/got/three_eyed_raven.php) inspired brews, but are there any others that originated from works of fiction?

Comment: Interesting question. I know of a few brews which I really wish existed.

Comment: Did the game of thrones beers really exist as fictional beers? I don't remember many references to beer, and certainly not the same styles as the beers they've been making.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Beer Advocate website](http://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/888/51478/), Romulan Ale from Star Trek is brewed by *Cervecería Centro Americana* in South Africa. A search in Google Images will produce several images of the bottles. I have included a link to one image.

[image: Romulan Ale]

[Romulan Ale](http://images1.browardpalmbeach.com/imager/u/original/6892103/romulanale_thelope.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not a fan [Butterbeer](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Butterbeer) from Harry Potter is apparently a thing. However I don't believe it's widely available and is pretty niche by the looks of it.

Comment: I don't think butterbeer contains beer though. From what I gather it's mostly butterscotch and schnapps.

Comment: @Matt - yes, it's a thing. I think there are some variations but, I think there's an official one.  It's called 'The Flying Cauldron' and it's made by Reed's Inc. - a natural soda company. As a lover of butterscotch and natural food, it's excellent, imho.

Comment: @Jaken - it is non-alcoholic but, if it's made with malted barley, it's technically beer. :D (Not sure myself, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Olde Frothingslosh started as a joke.  Not quite from a book, but possibly of interest.

[Olde Frothingslosh Pale Stale Ale](http://hoaxes.org/weblog/comments/olde_frothingslosh_pale_stale_ale)

Answer (score 2):

[Discworld Ales](http://www.discworldales.co.uk/) have a range of drinks inspired by the Terry Pratchett novels! I've not tasted any myself but they were well received as a gift.

Answer (score 2):

Duff Beer

> "Duff Beer is a brand of beer that originally started as a fictional beverage on the animated series The Simpsons. Since then it has become a real brand of beer in a number of countries without permission or consent from its original creator, Matt Groening, and has resulted in legal battles with varying results. An official version of the beer is sold in three variations near The Simpsons Ride at Universal Studios." - [Duff Beer (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff_Beer)

Answer (score 2):

[Dagschotel](http://www.kampioenenbier.be)

In Belgium, there's a tv-show that's been running for 20 years.
One of the characters always orders a "dagschotel" (french: plat du jour, english: the dish of the day) when he orders a glass of beer.

A few weeks ago, some brewery makes bottles of Dagschotel.

Answer (score 2):

In Germany there is a famous comic book beer called **Bölkstoff**.
They also began producing it but nowadays it's rare, but you can get it online.

[image: Bölkstoff ad from bier-wein.de]

There are [films](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100912/) about Werner where he drinks this specific beer.

Rötger Feldmann is the author of these comic books and films. You can find info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6tger_Feldmann) and [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6tger_Feldmann) much more on the German wikipedia page.

If you have further questions about the films or the beer, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a `BreakingBad` based beer that you can [find here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Breaking-Bad-Schraderbrau-12-oz-Beer-Bottle-Labels-Set-of-Six-/251644344257)

[image]

> Schraderbräu is a homebrew beer brewed by Hank Schrader. He is seen bottling the beer in Breakage, the fifth episode of season 2. He offers a six-pack of the beer as a prize in a fundraiser in ABQ, the thirteenth episode of season 2.